Avidemux loads vertical video in horizontal orientation
I have recorded a video while holding phone vertically. It opens vertically on phone, as well as on PC, in VLC. However, when I load it in Avidemux it rotates the video to horizontal aspect rate.
I tried to fix video's metadata with ffmpeg (using different rotate params), but it seems to have no effect.
I know I can "fix" the video with Avidemux video filters but I don't want to re-encode the video again.
Are there other ffmpeg commands I can try to make Avidemux load the video in vertical orientation?

Edit: apparently, metadata is correct, it's just that Avidemux unfortunately ignores it by design.
